# Rollup from daily to weekly metric on the fly in clientside

Tags: javascript, highcharts, plotly

I have data in json format with date and values. Is it possible to switch from daily chart to weekly chart (rollup) through only any JavaScript based charting application , where i can mention the rollup function to be either sum or something else.
I want to avoid any server-side calculations.

Any suggestions or example will be of great help.

Comment: It can be easily done using Highstock `dataGrouping` property. Check this: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.line.dataGrouping, https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

Comment: Do you just want to switch between a daily and a weekly focus to the chart? Like in this first example with the buttons "1m", "6m" etc.? https://plot.ly/python/range-slider/